# External css background image not working in IE internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ds1.truefitcorp.com/store-nem/6.24.0.3/resources/store/nem/css/fitrec-responsive.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="tfc-cfg-widget tfc-fitrec-result">
     <div class="tfc-cfg-logo"></div>
      <p>Which Size Fits Me?</p>
     <div>
 </body>
</html>
```

inside external css we have background image for class tfc-cfg-logo but IE alone background image not working because all the browsers checking for image in external css but IE checking in my code base.
 inside external css like this

```
 .tfc-cfg-widget.tfc-fitrec-result .tfc-cfg-logo {
    background-image: url(../images-snapshot/responsive/logo/bg-logo-red.svg);
 }
```

required output is **T** logo in IE [image]

Comment: It works for me in IE11 and IE10 (i've tested with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahendwh2/9fektcbh/1/)). Does your program need to support the older versions (IE9, IE8, IE7)?

Comment: for me IE9 working not working for IE11, 10